# Unable to assign values to a 3D char array

Tags: java

Typing the following lines of code gives me errors:

```
private char[][][] amino = new char[4][4][4];
amino[2][1][3], amino[2][1][1], amino[2][1][0], amino[2][1][2] = 'A';
amino[1][2][3], amino[1][2][1], amino[1][2][0], amino[1][2][2] = 'R';
amino[0][0][3], amino[0][0][1] = 'N';
```

jGrasp (the IDE that I use) gives me error saying `']' expected`.

Tried it in Eclipse and also gives me a similar error. What am I doing wrong!

Comment: If you want to put multiple things on the left hand side of an assignment like this, separate them with equals signs, not with commas.

Comment: Two things, you can do assignment outside of a method, constructor or initialisation block. Two you can't do multiple assignment this way...

Comment: ^did you mean to say "can't do assignment outside of a method" because I'm doing this outside of a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commas between `amino[2][1][3], amino[2][1][1],...` are not correct Java syntax.  Try this:

```
amino[2][1][3] = amino[2][1][1] = amino[2][1][0] = amino[2][1][2] = 'A';
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant use variables like this.

You can use multiple declaration of variables of same type with adding the same value into them. But there are few restrictions :

You can do this :

```
    int a = 3, b = 5;
```

But you cant do this later :

```
     a = 1, b = 7;
```

For example this >

```
private char[][][] amino1, amino2, amino3 = new char[4][4][4];
```

Adds to amino3 the a new empty array of 4x4x4 and the amino1 and amino2 stays uninitialized.

Comment: However, this doesn't give both `a` and `b` the value `4`

Comment: I tried it with a single field at a time:

>amino[2][1][3] = 'A';

Still gives me the same error. I'm starting to doubt whether java even supports 3D arrays... :(

Comment: @user1766889 All code that is *not* a declaration of some sort needs to be in a method body. Are you assignments contained in a method?